# Python 2.5 informixdb connect parameters

Tags: python, informix

I use Python 2.5 and informixdb. I want to connect with the database, but what are the parameters for the informixdb.connect() method? 
I have

- Hostname
- Port
- Databasename
- User
- Password

But what is the right order? Or how is the dsn String build?

The official documentation does not really help me.

The documentation says i can use

```
informixdb.connect(dsn)
```

but they do not explain how a DataSourceString should looks like. What arguments and in which order are needed.

[Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id40) is an link to the documentation.

And i know Python 2.5 is very old, but the database does not support Python 3.x i have tried it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. What is missing from the documentation? There isn't much detail in your question and 2.5 is very out of date.

Comment: The fact that the database doesn't support Python 3 doesn't stop you using 2.7.

Comment: Okay, but then I will have the same problem, still with Python 2.7 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at https://sourceforge.net/projects/informixdb/:

> To do anything useful with InformixDB one must connect to a database. This is accomplished by calling informixdb.connect:

```
>>> import informixdb
>>> conn = informixdb.connect('db@daniel', user='me', password='something')
>>> conn
<_informixdb.Connection object at 0xb7d08e90>
```

> informixdb.connect takes three arguments: A dsn which identifies the database and server to connect to, as recognized by ESQL's CONNECT statement (e.g. 'database@server', 'database', '@server') plus an optional user and a corresponding password.
>
> If the dsn doesn't include a servername the value of the environment variable INFORMIXSERVER is used. When connecting without specifying the name of the database no database will be selected. This is useful for setting up a new database from within InformixDB.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the new "IfxPy" OpenInformix module?

https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy

It has support for both 2.x and 3.x versions of Python.

Comment: Thanks, possibly i will try it, but actual informixdb works for me.